# How to launch google maps from image button in a list view?

Tags: c#, image, xamarin

I have an image button in my listview and I want to open google maps when press here is my code

```
 private async void pin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        await Launcher.OpenAsync(this.BindingContext.ToString());
    }
```

here is my XAML

```
 <ListView  ItemTapped="MTZ_ItemTapped" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CL }" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"   >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                     <StackLayout >
                                <ImageButton  Source="pin4"  IsVisible="{Binding NIsVisible}" Clicked="pin_Clicked"></ImageButton>
                          </StackLayout>
                     </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


</ListView>
```

here is my property

```
 public class Person
    {
        public string CITY2 { get; set; }
    } 
public ObservableCollection<Person> CL { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>() 
    {
        new Person() { CITY2="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=30.199097,31.137771"}
    }
```

and here is the error 
  'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. 
      so then where is the problem or what is the right code syntax? 
      thx :)

Comment: is your ImageButton inside of a DataTemplate?  You can't next items directly inside of a ListView like that

Comment: yup it is in an item template within data template and view sell i just thought i souldnt write it to save some space

Comment: if you do that, please use "..." or something to indicate that you've purposely left something out, otherwise your code appears to be broken

Comment: sry my bad , i edited the xaml code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you don't need to specify a `BindingContext` on your `ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton Source="pin4" IsVisible="{Binding NIsVisible}" Clicked="pin_Clicked" />
```

then in your handler

```
var btn = (ImageButton)sender;
var item = (Person)btn.BindingContext;
await Launcher.OpenAsync(item.CITY2);
```